# How to add css to a hover::after psudo element SVG?

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
.prevdiv:hover::after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg class="noimg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="arcs"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>');
}
.noimg:hover{
background-color:grey;
}
```

As of now, when I hover over the element it works perfectly, however, how do I add css to the element so that if I hover over the SVG it will show a background color? I cannot seem to style the SVG or add any hover effects. I tried adding the CSS directly into the SVG code, but that didnt work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around, it seems the issue is with dom loading. You are adding an element after all the elements are registered to dom. By adding a new one, the browser is not adding a CSS trigger for it. It is a similar issue to adding triggers to dynamically added elements with JavaScript. I have made a fairly simple workaround for it. There might exist a more elegant solution.

```css
.prevdiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.noimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.prevdiv:hover .noimg {
  display: block;
}

.noimg:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="prevdiv">
  <svg class="noimg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="arcs"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/couvpzre/

P.S. It might be a bug in browsers, but that requires far more research.

Comment: i figured i could do this one, but this is adding the svg to the HTML instead of the css.

Comment: In my mind, SVG does not belong in CSS as it is HTML. I can see the appeal, but sadly browsers do not like dynamic elements. Why, I cannot answer that, that is a question to browser guys. If you find an alternative solution, let me know.